# Using bash variable in a command line tool such as bcftools

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing, bioinformatics

I have a bash script which takes arguments and then runs the program bcftools:

```
$infile = $1
$outfile = $2
$pop1 = $3
$pop2 = $4
```

I would like to use the pop1 and pop2 arguments as a parameter, so in the below command, `AFR_AF` would be replaced by `pop1`, and `EUR_AF` by `pop2`:

```
bcftools view -i 'min(AFR_AF>0) & min(EUR_AF>0) & min(AFR_AF<1) & min(EUR_AF<1)' $infile > $outfile
```

However, if I use the same syntax as I have done for the in and out files (e.g. `$pop1`, I get an error because bcftools is not recognising the variable. How can I use command line variables as arguments for other tools?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

outFolder=$1
pop1=$2
pop2=$3
arr=($(seq 1 22 && echo X && echo Y))

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
bcftools view -i 'min("$pop1">0) & min("$pop2">0) & min("$pop1"<1) & min("$pop2"<1)' chr"$i".vcf.gz |
bcftools query -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t%REF\t%ALT\t%AA[\t%GT]\n' | 
awk '{if(length($3)==1 && length($4)==1) print}' > $outFolder/"$i".txt; done
```

I execute it with the following command:

```
./EHHparser1.sh EHH/ AFR_AF EUR_AF
```

And get this error repeated for each loop:

```
Wrong operator in string comparison: min("$pop1">0) & min("$pop2">0) & min("$pop1"<1) & min("$pop2"<1) [(null),$pop1]
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please provide more details here with your script and also paste the exact error you are getting while running your script.

Comment: hi, I have added my script, the command to run it, and the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to use double quotes rather than single as expressions do not expand in single quotes:

```
bcftools view -i "min($pop1>0) & min($pop2>0) & min($pop1<1) & min($pop2<1)" $infile > $outfile
```

Comment: What's the hacky way to print a variable with using `'` `'` single quotes? `var1=value1; eval echo variable var1 has value: ${var1}; echo 'variable var1 has value: ${var1}'; eval echo 'variable var1 has value: ${var1}'` the last command will. I know evals are not that great security wise and I also know the issue was with not using `"` double quotes but even with `'` single quotes, it's possible if you use `eval`. Again, this is not recommended though.